# C#: Mass substring filtering

Tags: c#, sql

At the moment, I'm trying to build a mapping function with my program so someone can enter a human readable name to a serial number, for example:

```
if the string contains "829283" display the name "Test Company".
```

The client has the ability to be be able to create as many of these rules are they wish, they are stored in an SQL table with the following layout:P

```
| PROFILE  | FILTER | MAPPEDTO |
 Profile1   8273     MyCompany
 Profile1   HT75     ThatOther1
```

So basically, I want the program to run through all of the items that are fetched from a text file and then check each line (around 250ish) for any occurrence of any of the "FILTER" values from the table, if the program is to find a filter value, it will then fill another column with the company name.

I can't think of a way of doing this so I would appreciated any help you guys could provide.

Thank you

Comment: 250 lines is nothing. What have you tried so far? Also, are you using an ORM to access your sql? Also, are the values unique (both in filter and in the 'mappedto')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex to find the first two occurrences of the quoted string.

```
string s = "if the string contains \"829283\" display the name \"Test Company\".";
string pattern = ".*\"(.*)\".*\"(.*)\"";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
if (m.Success)
{
    string filter = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string mappedTo = m.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Then you query your database and update/insert the records accordingly

Comment: Thank you for this, threw a procedure together using this code.